# What does PLAINTEXT keyword means in Kafka configuration?

Tags: apache-kafka

In [Apache Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) they use keyword *PLAINTEXT* as a protocol in many default settings:

e.g. 
`listeners=PLAINTEXT://broker1:9091,SSL://broker1:9092`

Does it represent just a default non-SSL protocol and if so, why they use *PLAINTEXT* keyword for that?

Comment: https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plain_text_protocol ...

Comment: @Pogrindis I am not sure it has the same usage as in Kafka configuration?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) for `listeners` states:

> Comma-separated list of URIs we will listen on and the listener names.
>   If the listener name is not a security protocol,
>   listener.security.protocol.map must also be set.

So `PLAINTEXT` in your example is the security protocol used on the listener. You can find the list of supported protocols and their respective meanings in the [SecurityProtocol Javadocs](http://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/security/auth/SecurityProtocol.html).

`PLAINTEXT` means the listener will be without authentication and non-encrypted.

Comment: How about PLAINTEXT_HOST?